# Search in whole Active Directory Forest without using GC

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap

Lets imagine that I have below Forest:

```
- home.org (root domain)
  - child1.home.org (child domain 1)
  - child2.home.org (child domain 2)
    - ...
```

And I want to find all AD Groups in my Forest by some LDAP filter.

Of cause I can use GC, but it's not my case because I want to retrieve attributes which does not exist in GC (managedBy just for example).

I thought that I can enable Chase Referrals and search using BasedDN from root domain. But looks like Referrals incompatible with paged queries (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2561166). I want to use paged queries because I want to receive ALL groups despite the possible limitations on the server (MaxPageSize limitation on server side).

Is it correct to say: to solve this problem I should execute LDAP queries through ALL domains independently without Chase Referrals? Or maybe someone has a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The KB gives a few workarounds but you're likely going to need to iterate through the domain hierarchy. To your question about a more elegant solution, you could simply add `managedBy` to the partial attribute set and then it would be available in the Global Catalog.